# How can I use \lVert and \rVert norm symbols (‖x‖) with the Iwona math font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, math-operators

I want to use `\lVert` and `\rVert` to denote the vector norm.
[image: "Testing ||x||." in CM]

With Computer Modern this works quite fine. But when trying to use Iwona as a math font, I run into trouble:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
Testing $\norm{x}$.
\end{document}
```

[image: "Testing x." in Iwona]

I never had any problems using Iwona as a math font, even with much more exotic symbols. I'm a bit surprised this occurs at this point and of course I'd like to know how to fix it.

Comment: What happens if you just use \|x\| for norm?

Comment: @PredragPunosevac Good question. The result is the same unfortunately :/

Comment: @Christian It's a bug that should be reported.

Comment: @egreg Ok, I sent Janusz a mail.

Comment: Two years have gone by without any reply and without the problem being fixed so it's probably safe to say by now that Iwona Math is no longer actively supported.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For very strange reasons, the slot `"6B` in the font `sy-iwona` is empty. The `\lVert` and `\rVert` commands point to that slot, so you can't see any symbol because it's not there to begin with. The definition of `\lVert` and `\rVert` given by `amsmath` are

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lVert}
  {\mathopen}{symbols}{"6B}{largesymbols}{"0D}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rVert}
  {\mathclose}{symbols}{"6B}{largesymbols}{"0D}
```

which mean: in normal size take the character living in the `symbol` font in slot `"6B` while for bigger sizes take the character living in the `largesymbols` font in slot `"0D`. The difference between the two is that the former is given `\mathopen` type, the latter is `\mathclose`.

Indeed

```
$\norm[\big]{x}$
```

works, because the bigger delimiter is found.

[image]

There's not so much to do except taking the symbol from another font, for instance

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareSymbolFont{extrasymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lVert}
  {\mathopen}{extrasymbols}{"6B}{largesymbols}{"0D}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rVert}
  {\mathclose}{extrasymbols}{"6B}{largesymbols}{"0D}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
Testing $\norm{x}$.

Testing $\norm[\big]{x}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, a compatible candidate would be Kurier, which also lacks the symbol.

A different solution, that doesn't require a substitute font, is to emulate the symbol at the size it's missing.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\xnorm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\NewDocumentCommand{\norm}{som}
 {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\xnorm*{#3}}
   {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\mathopen{|\mkern-.8mu|}#3\mathclose{|\mkern-.8mu|}}
     {\xnorm[#2]{#3}}%
   }
 }


\begin{document}
Testing $\norm{x}$.

Testing $\norm[\big]{x}$.
\end{document}
```

The `\norm` symbol does like `xnorm` unless it has no optional argument, in which case the two bars are produced from the single bar.

[image]

If you want a definition that works without doing the hack when the bug is fixed, you can do like this:

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \iffontchar\textfont2 "6B
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
  \else
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\xnorm{\lVert}{\rVert}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\norm}{som}
     {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
       {\xnorm*{#3}}
         {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
           {\mathopen{|\mkern-1mu|}#3\mathclose{|\mkern-1mu|}}
           {\xnorm[#2]{#3}}%
       }%
    }
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Testing $\norm{x}$.

Testing $\norm[\big]{x}$.

\end{document}
```

It works with all fonts so long as they don't use bizarre slots for the double vertical bar. It will define `\norm` in the easier way if the character exists, otherwise it will do the hack.

Comment: I think .8mu is a tiny bit too wide, 1mu works better for me but other than that, this is an ingenious hack :)

Comment: @Christian Maybe you're right. I added a better hack that will use the correct glyph once the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT for left/right.  While David Carlisle points out that my solution does not work for vertically scaled `\left` `\right` syntax, the `\stretchleftright{}{}{}` syntax of the `scalerel` package takes care of it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\def\lVert{\mid\!\mid}
\def\rVert{\mid\!\mid}
\begin{document}
Testing $\norm{x}$.
Testing $\norm{\frac{x}{y}}$.
Testing $\stretchleftright{\lVert}{\frac{x}{y}}{\rVert}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That wouldn't work at bigger sizes the `\left\right` added by the paired delimiter declaration would only apply to one of the bars.

Comment: No it needs to be a single character.

Comment: Ok, that's one way to solve this …

Comment: I didn't know about this `scalerel` feature. This might come in handy :)

Comment: @Christian.  Version 1.5 scalerel just got uploaded today...might take a few days to propagate.  But it fixes some package conflicts that arose with version 1.4.