# Getting the || sign while using Kurier

Tags: math-mode, fonts

If I compile the file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\begin{document}   
  $\|x\|$
\end{document}
```

all I get is a `x`, whereas what I should get is `||x||`. I found a way around this problem, which consists in typing `\left\|x\right\|`. Is this a known bug? Is there a better way of dealing with it?

Comment: Does `\lVert...\rVert` produce the same problem? P.S. Nice to see you here!

Comment: Yes. Using `\lVert...\rVert` (and the `amsmath` package), the result is the same.

Comment: See, for a very similar situation, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114834/4427 Kurier and Iwona are essentially the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here there is the same your question with the [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/W5fewiXHSKM) of the excellent user @egreg since 2010-11-30:

> It seems that the font developer forgot to add the correct symbol: slot "6B in `sy-kurrierz` is empty.

`\left\| x \right\|` works.

Comment: Good hunting! Fatto buona caccia!

Comment: @egreg Ahahaahahahahahhaha. LOL. I'm absolutely not in favour of the hunting :-). I often find what I'm looking for on the net, and I also tell my students. When my students must to find something into web the right keywords they are indispensable. :-)

Comment: @egreg is not it wrong to add `\left` and `\right` to every math expression e.g. inline math?

Comment: @manooooh This is an emergency. `;-)`