# font, text style etc

Tags: fonts, packages, fontsize, displaystyle

This might be awkward to ask but just wonder if by any chance one could inform me:

I just like very much the font and the text style used in this report here

[https://mast.queensu.ca/~math472/NaciSaldi.pdf](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emath472/NaciSaldi.pdf)

Could anyone by any chance tell me what usepackages and font need to be used to get this type of output? Thanks so much.

Comment: `\usepackage{iwona}` Caveat: if you need the norm symbol, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114834/4427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `\usepackage[light,math]{iwona}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[light,math]{iwona}

\begin{document}

% bottom of page 2 in the linked document

In addition, we have the following assumptions:
\begin{itemize}
\item $X_{t-1}\in\mathbf{B}(X)$ and $X_{t-1}\cap X_{t'-1}=\emptyset$, $\forall t\ne t'$.
\item $A_t\in\mathbf{B}(A)$ and $A_{t-1}\cap A_{t'-1}=\emptyset$, $\forall t\ne t'$.
\item $j(A_t)=X_{t-1}$ or $j^{-1}(X_{t-1})=A_t$ and specifies the admissible control
      space for state $X_{t-1}$, $\forall t$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need the norm symbol `\|` (as well as `\lVert` or `\rVert`), see my answer to [How can I use \lVert and \rVert norm symbols (‖x‖) with the Iwona math font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114830/4427)

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh